# I have no Idea why is my min function not working it keeps on giving me 0 as an answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So this the function code i came up with I do not know what is wrong with it.
It keeps giving 0 as my code.

```js
function minValue(array) {
  let min = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[j][i] == "string") {
        min = Math.min(min, parseInt(array[j][i]));
      } else {
        min = Math.min(min, array[j][i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return min;
}
let matrix = [
  [57, 71, 37, 99, 62, '83', '95', '54', 38, 25],
  [8, 64, 100, '51', 43, 21, 21, 33, 11, 43],
  [67, 25, 45, 67, 88, 72, 74, 77, 53, 38]
];

console.log(minValue(matrix));
```

I keep on getting 0 as my answer.

Comment: It looks to give `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined @ JS line 5` as an answer.

Comment: `array[j][i]` -> `array[i][j]`

Comment: what do u want to do exactly

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't work because you use `0` as the initial value, and it's smaller than all other values. Use `Infinity` as the initial value.

Note: you've switch between `i` and `j` here - `array[j][i]`. I would also remove the condition, and always convert to number (I've used the `+` operator here).

```js
function minValue(array) {
  let min = Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      min = Math.min(min, +array[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return min;
}

const matrix = [
  [57, 71, 37, 99, 62, '83', '95', '54', 38, 25],
  [8, 64, 100, '51', 43, 21, 21, 33, 11, 43],
  [67, 25, 45, 67, 88, 72, 74, 77, 53, 38]
];

console.log(minValue(matrix));
```

Another options is to flatten matrix to a single array, map all items to numbers, and spread into `Math.min()`:

```js
const minValue = array => Math.min(...array.flat().map(Number));

const matrix = [
  [57, 71, 37, 99, 62, '83', '95', '54', 38, 25],
  [8, 64, 100, '51', 43, 21, 21, 33, 11, 43],
  [67, 25, 45, 67, 88, 72, 74, 77, 53, 38]
];

console.log(minValue(matrix));
```